# Unable to view the results of a JavaScript function on a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, function, validation, math

```js
function calculate() { //Edit use () not {}
//Edit, use getElementById to get elements and validate return
    let hour = document.getElementById("hour")
       ,minute = document.getElementById("minute");
    if ( hour != undefined && hour.value != undefined ) {
       hour = Number(hour.value);
    }
    if ( minute != undefined && minute.value != undefined ) {
       minute = Number(minute.value);
    }
    alert("hour: " + hour + ", minute: " + minute);

    let actualHour = Math.ceil(parseFloat(hour + "." + minute))
       ,additionalCharge = 0.75, minimumCharge = 3.00
       ,maximumCharge = 12.00, totalCost = 0.0;
    alert("actualHour: " + actualHour);

    if( actualHour >= 24 ){
        totalCost = 12.00;
    } else if ( actualHour <=2 ){
        totalCost = 3.00;
    }
    if ( actualHour > 2 && actualHour < 24 ) {
        let countedHourForAdditionalCharge = actualHour - 2;
        totalCost = 3.00 + countedHourForAdditionalCharge * 0.75;

        if ( totalCost > 12.00 ) {
            totalCost = 12.00;
        }
    }
    alert("total charge: " + totalCost);
}
```

```html
<b>Hours:</b><input type="text" name="hour" id="hour"/>
<b>Minutes:</b><input type="text" name="minute" id="minute"/>
<button type= "button" onclick="calculate()" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

I am writing a program to display parking charges based on the hour and minutes a user inputs. I have an HTML code and a JavaScript code, but upon clicking the "Calculate" button on the HTML page, nothing happens. I am not sure how to display the results. I would like some advice on which method would be the easiest to get the function to work and to display the result.

The constraints for the JavaScript function are the following:

- The garage charges a $3.00 minimum fee to park for up to two hours.
- The garage charges a $3.00 minimum fee to park for up to two hours.
- The garage charges an additional $0.75 for each hour or part thereof in excess of two hours.
- The maximum charge for any given 24-hour period is $12.00.
- The hour is rounded upward to its nearest integer. (If someone parks for 4 hours and 35 minutes, it will be rounded to 5 hours)

Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" action="/Users/wilson/Desktop/form.html" onsubmit="event.calculate(); method"POST">
<b>Hours:</b><input type="text" name="hour" id="hour"/>
<b>Minutes:</b><input type="text" name="minute" id="minute"/>
<button type= "button" onclick="calculate()" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function calculate() { //Edit use () not {}
//Edit, use getElementById to get elements and validate return
    let hour = document.getElementById("hour")
       ,minute = document.getElementById("minute");
    if ( hour != undefined && hour.value != undefined ) {
       hour = Number(hour.value);
    }
    if ( minute != undefined && minute.value != undefined ) {
       minute = Number(minute.value);
    }
    alert("hour: " + hour + ", minute: " + minute);

    let actualHour = Math.ceil(parseFloat(hour + "." + minute))
       ,additionalCharge = 0.75, minimumCharge = 3.00
       ,maximumCharge = 12.00, totalCost = 0.0;
    alert("actualHour: " + actualHour);

    if( actualHour >= 24 ){
        totalCost = 12.00;
    } else if ( actualHour <=2 ){
        totalCost = 3.00;
    }
    if ( actualHour > 2 && actualHour < 24 ) {
        let countedHourForAdditionalCharge = actualHour - 2;
        totalCost = 3.00 + countedHourForAdditionalCharge * 0.75;

        if ( totalCost > 12.00 ) {
            totalCost = 12.00;
        }
    }
    alert("total charge: " + totalCost);
}
```

Comment: Have you took a look at the Dev Console? There might be an error message waiting for you.

Comment: Try closing the quotes after onclick:)

Comment: function should be defined as function name(){body}   not function name{}{body}

Comment: So many syntax errors, missing ';' on many lines, incorrect use of () instead of {}, parameters not encapsulated with "".

Comment: @SPlatten, You updated the code and it seems correct to me now, if there is code logic issue then my answer won;t help OP. Should I delete my answer

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar, no, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few changes I made, Please check it.

- `()` is used as a post fix to function not `{}`. `{}` is used to define scope of function.
- I used button with onclick function in HTML

```js
function calculate() {
    var hour = document.getElementById("hour").value;
    var minute = document.getElementById("minute").value;
    
    //Updated
    if(hour === "" && minute === ""){
      alert("Please provide valid inputs");
      return false;
      }
//    alert("hour "+hour)
//    alert("minute "+minute)
    
    let minimumCharge = 3.00;
    let additionalCharge = 0.75;
    let maximumCharge = 12.00;
    let actualHour = Math.ceil(parseFloat(hour+"."+minute));
        alert("actualHour: "+actualHour);
    let totalCost = 0.0;


    if(actualHour >=24){
        totalCost = 12.00;
    }

    if(actualHour <=2){
        totalCost = 3.00;
    }

    if(actualHour >2 && actualHour <24){
        let countedHourForAdditionalCharge = actualHour - 2;

        totalCost = 3.00 + countedHourForAdditionalCharge * 0.75;

        if(totalCost > 12.00){
            totalCost = 12.00;
        }
    }
    alert("total charge: " +totalCost);
}
```

```html
<b>Hours:</b><input type="text" name="hour" id="hour">

<b>Minutes:</b><input type="text" name="minute" id="minute">

<button type= "button" onclick="calculate()" value= "Submit">Submit</button>
                        <!-- >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>^ you were missing " -->
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to make it so that an input is required otherwise it will return a message saying "Please input values."? I tried putting required in the HTML code, but it seems as JavaScript overrides it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

not

```
function calculate{} {...}
```

should be

```
function calculate() {...}
```